# Is it possible to fake other OS platforms for unit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, cross-platform

I make cross-platform and multi platform tools. They for example load different modules depending on the runtime platform.

Obviously, I won't be able to fully test them in Visual Studio on Windows, but I could at least test if they detect the runtime platform correctly and if they load appropriate modules.

The system checks are pretty standard:

```cs
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOsPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) { /* do the Linux thing */ }
```

I test Linux code just by publishing a Linux executable (as standard console application)
and then just output the test results to the console.

It would be cool if I would be able to add some XUnit tests to my Visual Studio solution
that test some of this code.

Comment: You could abstract that runtime information code so you are in control. That way a mock can be done for your tests as needed. I tend to treat framework code as 3rd party code. If I have no control over it for what I want to do, then it needs to be wrapped.

Comment: extract a platform-helper and mock that.

Comment: Well, I had that in mind, the mocking thing. But additional abstraction layer would collide with the goal of making the module as straightforward as it gets. As I reconsidered everything - I NEED to test the system things on Linux VM anyway. Some even on IoT, because of specific hardware. So maybe there's no need to duplicate tests. The test in VS must just test the exact behavior on Windows. So either do things the Windows way, or throw the expected exception.